# Query Multiple Colums from the same field in the same Table In Two different Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

This tblName Table Has 4 Column {Date}, {Status}, {Meal}, {Type}
I want to use condition in side subquery to show in a different column

```
Select Date, Status, Meal
    (Select Type as Special
     from tblName
     where Type In ('SSS','MMM')),
    (Select Type as Normal
     from tblName
     where Type Not IN ('SSS','MMM'))
From tblName
```

I get The error Message

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a sqlfiddle example and a desired result?
To your problem: Run `Select Type as Special
     from tblName
     where Type In ('SSS','MMM')` and `Select Type as Normal
     from tblName
     where Type Not IN ('SSS','MMM')` on your table and see that there is a list of results returned which is not allowed in your place when used inside of a `select from` list.

Comment: I will try my best to explain, sorry this is a little complicated as I am new into this.  The result that I want is A new table separated column 'Type' in the new name as Special and Normal in different result. is there any way to do that?

Comment: in 'Type' Colum has many different Values and I want to create a new column which have only 'SSS' and 'MMM' Values and Other Value That are NOT IN 'SSS' and "MMM' will store in 'Normal' Column

Comment: Is `Type` different for a number of rows where otherwise `Date`, `Status` and `Meal` are equal? Please consider a minimal sqlfiddle example, it saves us a lot of comments here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is: for each record in tblName select all types from tblName where type is in ('SSS','MMM'). And all these types shall be shown as one column in the tblName's result row. That doesn't work of course. What you *can* do is select *one* value for each record in in tblName. For instance `max(type)`.

It seems, however, what you actually want is simply display 'special' when type is 'SSS' or 'MMM' and 'normal' otherwise?

```
Select Date, Status, Meal,
  case when Type In ('SSS','MMM') then 'special' als 'normal' end as kind
From tblName;
```

Or display the type in two separate columns?

```
Select Date, Status, Meal,
  case when Type In ('SSS','MMM') then Type end as Special,
  case when Type Not In ('SSS','MMM') then Type end as Normal
From tblName;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be Something Like this:

```
Select t1.Date, t1.Status, t1.Meal
    (t2.Type as Special),
    (t3.Type as Normal )
From tblName t1 LEFT JOIN
tblName t2
ON t1.ID=t2.ID
LEFT JOIN 
tblName t3
ON t1.ID=t3.ID
where t2.Type Not In ('SSS','MMM') 
OR t3.Type In ('SSS','MMM')
```

OR

Conditional Aggregation

```
Select Date, Status, Meal
    (case when Type IN ('SSS','MMM') then Type else null end case) 
     )Type as Special,
   (case when Type NOT IN ('SSS','MMM') then Type else null end case) 
     )Type as Normal
From tblName
```